# Exclude global patterns in setuptools.packages.find is not working

Tags: python, setuptools, packaging

I have a package `Foo` where I want to exclude both the `test` files located in folders `tests` and the file(s) `conftest.py`.

My `pyproject.toml` configuration is:

```
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
exclude = ['Foo*tests', '*conftest']
include = ['Foo*']
```

The test files are correctly excluded, but not the `conftest` file. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you try `'*conftest.py` or `*conftest*` ?

Comment: @furas Yes, `*conftest*` is not working. Surprisingly, `['*conftest*', 'Foo*tests']` is producing the same result; `conftest.py` still present and the test files in `tests` folders absent.

Comment: @furas Looks like maybe it only accepts patterns to directories?

Comment: Or not, I added `Foo*utils` which is a module, and it was still included. Only works for `Foo*tests` for some weird reason..

Comment: `MANIFEST` works but looks ugly. c.f. https://discuss.python.org/t/ignoring-py-files-in-sdist-and-bdist-with-setuptools-requires-a-manifest/39276